# Encoding settings in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, handbrake

I have a MKV file with the following encoding settings. I know the file was encoded in Handbrake because it says so in the meta data.

```
cabac=1
ref=5
deblock=1:0:0
analyse=0x3:0x133
me=umh
subme=9
psy=1
psy_rd=1.00:0.15
mixed_ref=1
me_range=24
chroma_me=1
trellis=2
8x8dct=1
cqm=0
deadzone=21,11
fast_pskip=1
chroma_qp_offset=-4
threads=12
lookahead_threads=1
sliced_threads=0
nr=0
decimate=1
interlaced=0
bluray_compat=0
constrained_intra=0
bframes=5
b_pyramid=2
b_adapt=2
b_bias=0
direct=3
weightb=1
open_gop=0
weightp=2
keyint=240
keyint_min=23
scenecut=40
intra_refresh=0
rc_lookahead=60
rc=crf
mbtree=1
crf=27.0
qcomp=0.60
qpmin=0
qpmax=69
qpstep=4
vbv_maxrate=10000
vbv_bufsize=10000
crf_max=51.0
nal_hrd=none
filler=0
ip_ratio=1.40
aq=1:1.00
```

I have used FFMPEG for a while, but I am not sure what these settings are, what they do or how I can make FFMPEG encode with the same settings.

Answer (score 1):

All of these parameters are specific to the x264 encoder which is used to produce H.264 streams.

x264 has long since introduced a preset system whereby different permutations of values of these parameters can be set at once using `-preset value` in FFmpeg, e.g. `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v ibx264 -preset slow out.mp4`

AFAICT, the permutation of parameters shown in your file don't match any preset. However, you can set preset to slow, and then override the individual parameters, e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v ibx264 -preset slow -x264opts "me=umh:subme=9:psy_rd=1.00:0.15" out.mp4
```

For a guide to individual parameters, see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MeGUI/x264_Settings.